# Xamarin Forms : Is there any similar component like iOS UICollectionView for cross platform Xamarin?

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, uicollectionview, cross-platform

I want to implement component like iOS UICollectonView for Xamarin cross platform, How can I implement this? I know the grid layout but it doesn't fit my requirement perfectly. Is there any way to implement this? I want Gallary thumbnail type view with one row only and that should scroll horizontally.

Comment: Horizontall ListView with custom Cells

Comment: Yes, but also have requirement of thumbnails in vertical scroll where 3 thumbnails per row and I have to show as per response so possibly I have 7 thumbnails total.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this component which supports Xamarin.Forms

https://github.com/daniel-luberda/DLToolkit.Forms.Controls

[image]